# Alternative CLT for non-centered random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, central-limit-theorem

The central limit theorem for the i.i.d case states that for $X_k \sim \text{i.i.d.}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, we have that:

$$ \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k - n \mu}{\sigma\sqrt n } \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ or equivalently for $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$:

$$ \dfrac{S_n - E(S_n)}{\sqrt{Var(S_n)}} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$

I was reading the proof for the CLT and it seems to me that the need for writing it centered with $S_n-E(S_n)$ comes from the fact that the random variable $Z_n = \dfrac{S_n - E(S_n)}{\sqrt{Var(S_n)}}$ has zero mean and unit variance. This is convenient when considering the Taylor expansion for the characteristic function, because we'll have:

$$ \varphi_{Z_n}(t) = \left(1- \dfrac{t^2/2}{n} + o(1/n) \right)^n \to e^{t^2/2} \text{ as } n\to \infty$$

This is because the zero mean makes the term $ it E(X_1)=0$ for the Taylor expansion, thus making it simpler to evaluate the convergence as $n\to\infty$ for the characteristic function.

What I am wondering is: are there "versions" or "alternatives" for the central limit theorem for non-centered random variables? If so, what would be an example?

My goal is to understand how "flexible" I can be for convergence of random variables. I have seen some specific examples of convergence of random varaibles, as in Shiryaev's section of infinitely divisible distributions, but the formulation is again "centered". I know that the Lindeberg CLT works for non-i.i.d RV's, just independent ones, but the formulation is still in terms of the "centered" approach, only requiring the Lindeberg condition.

Thanks! :)

Comment: There are many variations on the theme of the CLT. The random variables you start with are "non-centered"; the ones that get centered are in the proof rather than in the theorem itself. If you imagine altering the proof to omit that centering step, doesn't that just add an extra complication?

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, I'll have somthing like $\varphi_n(t) = \left(1+\dfrac{it\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} - \dfrac{0.5 t^2}{n}+o(1/n)\right)^n$, but convergence is not so obvious in this case. Maybe with some conditions, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

IID conditions can be relaxed quite a bit into certain "mix" conditions.

But the CLT, in the form of $\sqrt{n} Z_n \rightarrow N()$, in distribution, necessarily requires that $E(Z_n) \rightarrow 0$, because $Z_n \rightarrow 0$ in distribution, and thus in probability.

So it has to be "centered" (using your terminology) asymptotically.

Comment: thanks! But my question will not necessarily be for the normal case, meaning that I could have some random variables under specific conditions that will converge in distribution for another random variable different than the normal (such as in Poisson Theorem). My point is that, in this cases, "centering" it might not be necessary, and I wonder if there are actual results about this.

Comment: As far as a I know, in CLT, the right-hand side is ALWAYS normal (while the left-hand side can be anything that satisfy certain mixing conditions).   If the right-hand side can be a non-normal distribution, and assuming you are not talking about stuff like I(1) processes, then I would be learning new things (Please share a reference.)  But even in that case, the left hand side still need to be "centered".  Sqrt of n goes to infinity.  So you need the other term to go to zero in order for the product to converge to something meaningful.